# Android Best Practices - Refactoring a big Activity class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, listeners

Looking to refactor a Google maps Activity class to something a little more maintainable.

Currently it implements the following interfaces:

`LocationListener`, `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

As well as this, it contains quite a number of helper methods.

I have a few questions relating to the best way of doing this.

1. Should I create static helper classes and leave my listener implementations in the Activity class?
2. Should I create helper classes and create instances of them, passing to their constructors everything I need? e.g. contexts.
3. Should I abstract my Activity class and implement each listener in its own class separately?

Thanks in advance.  I'd like to follow some sort of Android/Java standard before my technical debt builds up much further.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on how you intend to use the `Activity` in your app.

1. Should I create static helper classes and leave my listener implementations in the Activity class?
   **Answer**: This approach would work great if you intend to use the `Activity` in only 1 place in your app, and don't need to reuse the activity in different parts of your app. The reason is that you would have to make the helper functions very flexible (lots of if's) to be able to reuse those functions with the same `Activity`, but in difference situations and scenarios. See Option 3 for opposite of this.
2. Should I create helper classes and create instances of them, passing to their constructors everything I need? e.g. contexts.
   **Answer**: This might be the more complex route, but would give you the most flexibility in regards to features enabling/disabling in the maps. Let's say you wish to have map that only does 2 things. You could create a new `Activity` and call the 2 helper functions that would add those 2 features to the map. In another part of your app, you could call more helper function calls to add more features. This would also make the use of your maps the most uniform, since all features are added with the exact same helper function calls.
3. Should I abstract my `Activity` class and implement each listener in its own class separately?
   **Answer**: This approach should be used if you intend to reuse the exact same activity in different parts of you app. Let's say you want to display a map in an 'About' section and in various parts of your app. All maps shown would have exactly the same functions and would work exactly the same way. (To add a little more flexibility, you should create an `Abstract Fragment` with all the listeners implemented. That way you can easily reuse your `Fragment` in any part of your app by simply adding the `Fragment`.)

   I would personally do a combination of Option 2 and 3, because that way you could have `Fragments` you could add anywhere in your app, with whichever functions you wish to implement.